# How do you statically type a variable so it only takes an integer greater than 0

Tags: python

What I want to do is to create a class called `Pizza` that takes 2 inputs: `self` and `radius` where if you create an instance of `Pizza`, where you enter **anything** as the `radius` other than an integer greater than 0, it will print a statement saying: `'Sorry,  but that is an invalid input. A valid input is any integer greater than 0.'`

Here is what I have so far for my class `Pizza`, but I want to make changes so the above is true:

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
```

Comment: forget the fancy words, that sounds like a simple `if-else` statement

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292197/can-python-implement-dependent-types. Python doesn't provide support for dependent types, either for type hinting or at run-time.

Comment: @chepner, I know about that, but how do I make it not only accept integers, but only integers greater than 0. Also, it does allow static typing in version 3.6+ I believe

Comment: A dependent type is a type whose values can be constrained: in your case, you want a type `PositiveInt` which is an `int` whose values are greater than 0.

Comment: @PythonHunter type annotations are not static typing.

Comment: You don't want to do this. You're fighting the language. Include a guard clause (if-statement) that rejects values outside the acceptable range. If you need stronger type enforcement than that (you don't), Python is simply the wrong language for the task.

Comment: I'm curious why you specify that the radius should be an integer. Are other numeric types like float and decimal not appropriate to represent a radius?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco It is because floats sometimes acts funny, and I do not know how to get Decimal class.

Comment: @PythonHunter it is true that floats sometimes have "funny" behaviour, but honestly this is not a very good reason to opt for an integer type. They are distinct numeric types with a distinct purpose. If you want something to represent a "number", especially a length, you should use a float or similar. If you actually need an integral quantity, (for example a counter of something), then use an int type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizing [Python's error and exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) might be a more flexible approach.

Instead of hard coding an error response within the class definition (i.e. print out an error string), you instead notify the caller that an error condition has occurred and then an appropriate action for that context can be made (i.e. print out an error on the console, generate a graphical error prompt, ignore the error, try a different input, etc.).

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        if not isinstance(radius, int):
            raise ValueError('radius must be an integer')
        if not radius > 0:
            raise ValueError('radius must be greater than 0')
        self.radius = radius

inputs = [8, -8, 8.8, '8', 'foo']

print('\nTesting inputs and outputting error messages:')
for r in inputs:
    print('r: {} ({})'.format(r, type(r)))
    try:
        p = Pizza(r)
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Unable to create Pizza: {}'.format(e))
        continue
    print('p.radius: {}'.format(p.radius))

print('\nTesting inputs and silently discarding errors:')
for r in inputs:
    print('r: {} ({})'.format(r, type(r)))
    try:
        p = Pizza(r)
    except ValueError as e:
        continue
    print('p.radius: {}'.format(p.radius))
```

**Output**

```
$ python3 pizza.py

Testing inputs and outputting error messages:
r: 8 (<class 'int'>)
p.radius: 8
r: -8 (<class 'int'>)
Unable to create Pizza: radius must be greater than 0
r: 8.8 (<class 'float'>)
Unable to create Pizza: radius must be an integer
r: 8 (<class 'str'>)
Unable to create Pizza: radius must be an integer
r: foo (<class 'str'>)
Unable to create Pizza: radius must be an integer

Testing inputs and silently discarding errors:
r: 8 (<class 'int'>)
p.radius: 8
r: -8 (<class 'int'>)
r: 8.8 (<class 'float'>)
r: 8 (<class 'str'>)
r: foo (<class 'str'>)
```

Comment: When i did Pizza('s'), I got:
File "C:/Users/ian/PycharmProjects/compyre/test.py", line 4, in __init__
    raise ValueError('radius must be an integer')

I do not want the line 4 stuff to show

Comment: ok, also how do I close the question thing since I tried one of the answers and it worked.

Comment: I updated the example to demonstrate different approaches to error handling. In regards to closing the question, here are [the instructions for accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

this can be achieved by

```py
class Pizza:
     def __init__(self, radius):
            if isinstance(radius, int) and radius > 0 :
                self.radius = radius
            else:
                print('Sorry,  but that is an invalid input. A valid input is any integer greater than 0.')
```

Comment: Aren’t there better ways of checking whether or not something is an integer?

Comment: if **.isdigit()** can do the work why we have to go for another method..

Comment: if you have a better method please let us know i and we are eager to learn @AMC

Comment: I don’t think that “It works so who cares” is a particularly good attitude to have. For one, it does make your intent far less obvious than a solution using `type()` or `isinstance()`. While it might not necessarily matter here, I do know that `str.isdigit()` is not a valid way of checking whether or not a string can be converted to an int.

Comment: @AMC i didn't say that ** It works so who cares ** i am ready to learn please point us the correct way that's what i was asking.

Comment: You aren't checking if `radius` is actually an int-like object greater than 0, you are checking if ["if all characters in the [string conversion of radius] are digits and there is at least one character"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) types in python can specify arbitrary code for how they convert to string, just because an object represents itself as digits doesn't mean it actually has int-like behavior

Comment: @HymnsForDisco what do you mean by **just because an object represents itself as digits doesn't mean it actually has int-like behavior** this i don't get it . it would be much more helpful if you explain completly

Comment: @google "explain completely" is not so well defined, but to gain more understanding of my point, you will need to know that calling `str(object)` doesn't have any guarantees, it simply calls the [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) magic method of `object`.  This `__str__` method can, in theory, return any value, or nothing at all. Just because the returned object may be a string, and that string may be composed of digits, doesn't have any guarantee whatsoever about the other behavior of the object. At best we can hope that is an `int` or similar.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco in understand what you are saying . I updated my answer and excuse my terrible English .