# How to type-hint a container (list or tuple generally) having the same length than another ? built-in prefered

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting

I am new to type-hinting,
I wanted to know if there was a built-in python way to warn the user that an (optional) container argument should have the same length than an other, if it is specified.
They could be any length and should be iterable, that's why I titled list or tuple.
I was expecting something like that, if that makes sense :

```
def func(A_iterable: Iterable[float], B_iterable: Iterable[str * length(A_iterable) = None]
return
```

I do not need it to be actually evaluated : no need to diplay 4 if the first container has a length of 4, just that they should be the same size. But it seems that type hints are for type only..
I could use a doc-string to warn the user but I wanted something shorter. I was wondering if those kind hints were built-in since they seem useful.
If there is none, I am ok with using an external library.

PS :
I have seen the typings.Annotation module which apparently allows more annotations but I am using python 3.8 and I am not sure I can specify a number of elements as a str to the user.

I currently use simple strings as annotations like so

```
B_iterable: "Iterable[str * length(A_iterable)"
```

I was hoping not to have to build my own collection class just for a hint. However I tried to but I could make iterable containers thanks to typing.Protocols and a stackoverflow answer ([Typehints for Sized Iterable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427944/typehints-for-sized-iterable-in-python)) :

```
class SizedIterable(Protocol[T,A]):
def __init__(self):pass
def __iter__(self):pass
```

I can make a countable class by adding a `__len__` methods but that doesn't make it a possible annotation. Is it possible to customize the typing hint of a class ?

Comment: Perhaps duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43292197/5986907

Comment: This is only possible for Tuples, and then only if they have a definite size in the type e.g. `Tuple[A, B, C]` (len 3) and not `Tuple[A, ...]`.

Comment: you might also be interested in this PEP https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: What you are asking for sounds like dependent types, which Python's type system doesn't support